# An exercise about linear functionals

Tags: vector-spaces

How to prove the following exercise in section 14# of Halmos' "Finite Dimensional Vector Space":

[image]

In particular, I don't know why $y=\alpha z$ even for all $x$ that $[x,z]\neq0$.

BTW: in the book, $y(x)$ is represented as $[x, y]$, where $y$ is a linear functional on $V$, and $x\in V$.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the sections follows section 14#, particularly about the annihilators, I guess I have a proof.

Basically, $S^0=span(z)$ where S is a subspace of $V$ and $span(z)$ is a subspace of $V'$; Suppose that $dim\ V=dim\ V'=n$.

If $z=0\in V'$, it's trivial to see that $y=0=0\cdot z$;

If $z\neq0$ $\Rightarrow$ $dim\ span(z)=1$, $dim\ S = n-1$; With $T^0=span(y)$ where $S\subseteq T$, it's either that:

1. $T=V$, and $y=0$, or
2. $T=S$, and $span(y)=span(z)$.

for if otherwise ($T\neq V$ and $S\subset T$), then $\exists q\in T, q\notin S$ that $y(q)=0$. This implies that $dim\ span(S+q)=n-1+1=n$ which leads to the trivial case that $T=S=V$ and $y=\alpha z=0$.